# Is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sin {\left(n\pi +\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\log n}\right)}, \alpha<0$ divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I konw $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sin {\left(n\pi +\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\log n}\right)}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^n\sin {\left( \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\log n}\right)},$ if I could prove $\sin{\left( \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\log n}\right)}\nrightarrow 0$(Maybe it can be simplified to $\sin{n^{\alpha}},\alpha>0)$ ,then this series is divergent. But I don't konw how to get it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you not need to sum from $n=2$ as $\log 1=0$?

Answer (score 1):

For $\alpha<0$ and $n\to\infty$,
$$\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\log n}~\to\infty$$
and $\lim_{z\to\infty}\sin(z)$ is undefined, so the series diverges as the general term doesn't tend to $0$.

Comment: I am assuming that the series starts at $n=2$ too.

Comment: I think there's a problem with your deduction. For example $\{\sin n\pi \}$ is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

For $\alpha>0$, the general term is alternating and convergent to 0, so the series converge.

Comment: You have a different answer from the other one, why the general term is convergent to $0$?

Comment: The answers are not contradictory. One is for $\alpha>0$, the other for $\alpha<0$.